# Sample k random permutations without replacement in O(N)

Tags: python, algorithm, permutation

I need a number of unique random permutations of a list without replacement, efficiently. My current approach:

```
total_permutations = math.factorial(len(population))
permutation_indices = random.sample(xrange(total_permutations), k)
k_permutations = [get_nth_permutation(population, x) for x in permutation_indices]
```

where `get_nth_permutation` does exactly what it sounds like, efficiently (meaning O(N)). However, this only works for `len(population) <= 20`, simply because 21! is so mindblowingly long that `xrange(math.factorial(21))` won't work:

```
OverflowError: Python int too large to convert to C long
```

Is there a better algorithm to sample k unique permutations without replacement in O(N)?

Comment: Can't you simply call random.shuffle on range(len(population)) and check to see if you've seen it before?  (With some checks to make sure it's possible, i.e. that you're not requesting 10 unique samples from [0,1].)

Comment: interesting. python3 does not have this limitation. even ` >>> range(math.factorial(10000)) ` returns within seconds. however,` >>> len(range(math.factorial(10000)))` yields: ` OverflowError: Python int too large to convert to C ssize_t `

Comment: @ch3ka that's because in Python3 `range` returns a generator. However, when you try to coerce the generator from `range` into a list (to check it's length), you'll get an `OverflowError`.

Comment: @Wilduck of course. But the fact that py3s range() does something what py2s xrange() cannot in a real world problem just struck me a bit.

Comment: @DSM, as I read the question the requirement is to get selections from the range `[0,21!]` not `[0,21]`.

Comment: @MarkRansom, assuming `get_nth_permutation` returns the nth permutation (based on lexicographic sort order), the result of the OP's code is a list of `k` permutations of `population`. That can be achieved just as easily by repeated calls to `random.shuffle(population)`. But there are some [potential problems](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10233149/577088) with that approach.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of using `xrange` simply keep generating random numbers until you have as many as you need. Using a `set` makes sure they're all unique.

```
permutation_indices = set()
while len(permutation_indices) < k:
    permutation_indices.add(random.randrange(total_permutations))
```

Comment: I was about to write the same. There is no need to make a list of all possible permutations (or indices) when you already have `get_nth_permutation`

Comment: Works well for large n, but for small n (ie k not much smaller than total_permutations) this will perform poorly. Okay, but then again the above solution works for small n, so may I'll just do a split case.

Answer (score 6):

Up to a certain point, it's unnecessary to use `get_nth_permutation` to get permutations. Just shuffle the list!

```
>>> import random
>>> l = range(21)
>>> def random_permutations(l, n):
...     while n:
...         random.shuffle(l)
...         yield list(l)
...         n -= 1
... 
>>> list(random_permutations(l, 5))
[[11, 19, 6, 10, 0, 3, 12, 7, 8, 16, 15, 5, 14, 9, 20, 2, 1, 13, 17, 18, 4], 
 [14, 8, 12, 3, 5, 20, 19, 13, 6, 18, 9, 16, 2, 10, 4, 1, 17, 15, 0, 7, 11], 
 [7, 20, 3, 8, 18, 17, 4, 11, 15, 6, 16, 1, 14, 0, 13, 5, 10, 9, 2, 19, 12], 
 [10, 14, 5, 17, 8, 15, 13, 0, 3, 16, 20, 18, 19, 11, 2, 9, 6, 12, 7, 4, 1], 
 [1, 13, 15, 18, 16, 6, 19, 8, 11, 12, 10, 20, 3, 4, 17, 0, 9, 5, 2, 7, 14]]
```

The odds are overwhelmingly against duplicates appearing in this list for `len(l)` > 15 and `n` < 100000, but if you need guarantees, or for lower values of `len(l)`, just use a `set` to record and skip duplicates if that's a concern (though as you've observed in your comments, if `n` gets close to `len(l)!`, this will stall). Something like:

```
def random_permutations(l, n):    
    pset = set()
    while len(pset) < n:
        random.shuffle(l)
        pset.add(tuple(l))
    return pset
```

However, as `len(l)` gets longer and longer, `random.shuffle` becomes less reliable, because the number of possible permutations of the list increases beyond the period of the random number generator! So not all permutations of `l` can be generated that way. At that point, not only do you need to map `get_nth_permutation` over a sequence of random numbers, you also need a random number generator capable of producing every random number between `0` and `len(l)`! with relatively uniform distribution. That might require you to find a more robust source of randomness.

However, once you have that, the solution is as simple as [Mark Ransom](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10232691/577088)'s answer.

To understand why `random.shuffle` becomes unreliable for large `len(l)`, consider the following. `random.shuffle` only needs to pick random numbers between `0` and `len(l) - 1`. But it picks those numbers based on its internal state, and it can take only a finite (and fixed) number of states. Likewise, the number of possible seed values you can pass to it is finite. This means that the set of unique sequences of numbers it can generate is also finite; call that set `s`. For `len(l)! > len(s)`, some permutations can never be generated, because the sequences that correspond to those permutations aren't in `s`.

What are the *exact* lengths at which this becomes a problem? I'm not sure. But for what it's worth, the period of the mersenne twister, as implemented by `random`, is [2**19937-1](http://docs.python.org/library/random.html#module-random). The [shuffle docs](http://docs.python.org/library/random.html#random.shuffle) reiterate my point in a general way; see also what Wikipedia has to say on the matter [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle#Pseudorandom_generators:_problems_involving_state_space.2C_seeding.2C_and_usage).

Comment: Good caveat about the random number generator. I think there's a bug in `random_permutations`, the shuffled list is never added to the set.

Comment: @MarkRansom, you're right! That function was all wrong, but it's better now, I think. (Actually, looking at your answer, I inadvertently plagiarized it -- you will take that as a compliment, I hope.)

Comment: Thanks, quality answer. Why does random.shuffle get unreliable? I believe it's implemented as in-place Fisher-Yates shuffle, which only needs to pick random numbers between 0 and len(l)-1.

Comment: @Nkosinathi, my response didn't fit into a comment box, so I incorporated it into my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I had one implementation of nth_permutation (not sure from where I got it) which I modified for your purpose. I believe this would be fast enough to suit your need

```
>>> def get_nth_permutation(population):
    total_permutations = math.factorial(len(population))

    while True:
        temp_population = population[:]
        n = random.randint(1,total_permutations)
        size = len(temp_population)
        def generate(s,n,population):
            for x in range(s-1,-1,-1):
                fact = math.factorial(x)
                d = n/fact
                n -= d * fact
                yield temp_population[d]
                temp_population.pop(d)
        next_perm = generate(size,n,population)
        yield [e for e in next_perm]


>>> nth_perm = get_nth_permutation(range(21))
>>> [next(nth_perm) for k in range(1,10)]
```

Comment: Thanks, good idea as such, but we're running in the same problem that we had with `xrange`, this time with `random.randint`:

    `OverflowError: Python int too large to convert to C long`

Comment: @Nkosinathi: Strange as I just ran `random.randint(1,math.factorial(10000))` and after few seconds it returned a number of length 35659.

Comment: Ah, I just noticed that I had random imported from `numpy`, nod from the standard modules. True, `random.randint` can deal with 10000! effortlessly, `numpy.random.randint` apparently can't. Good to know :)

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be searching for the [Knuth Shuffle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth_shuffle)! Good luck!

Comment: post a comment to the OP question if you want to put simply a link. otherwise add some context, so that if the link goes dead/changes the answer will still be useful! ;)

Comment: Shuffling a list of length 21! isn't going to be practical.

Comment: @MarkRansom, I don't think that's what he's suggesting. Shuffling a 21-item list will "select" one from among 21! permutations, which seems to be what the OP wants.

Comment: @senderle is right. However, I need k unique permutations, I don't see how Knuth shuffle can guarantee this.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `itertools.islice` instead of `xrange()`:

> CPython implementation detail: xrange() is intended to be simple and
>   fast Implementations may impose restrictions to achieve this.  The C
>   implementation of Python restricts all arguments to native C longs
>   (“short” Python integers), and also **requires that the number of
>   elements fit in a native C long**. If a **larger range** is needed, an
>   alternate version can be crafted **using the itertools module**:
>   islice(count(start, step), (stop-start+step-1+2*(step<0))//step).