# python 2.7 xrange too big argument error

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
random.sample(xrange(lb), it)
```

when `lb` is larger it throws

> OverflowError: Python int too large to convert to C long

since xrange does need that in Python 2.7!

Is there a workout  around to this?

I tried from a different post this:

```
import itertools
xrange = lambda stop: iter(itertools.count().next, stop)
```

But random doesn't like that:

> TypeError: object of type 'callable-iterator' has no len()

Comment: possible duplicate of [\`xrange(2\*\*100)\` -> OverflowError: long int too large to convert to int](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1482480/xrange2100-overflowerror-long-int-too-large-to-convert-to-int)

Comment: no duplicate none of the solution work

Comment: but i think random is the problem. but in the doc nothing is written about a upper bound.

Comment: Please tell us which solutions you have tried, and show us the errors they give you when they fail.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sample k random permutations without replacement in O(N)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10232338/sample-k-random-permutations-without-replacement-in-on)